# Validations in ASP.NET Core 2.0: syntax vs validation problems

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

In my ASP.NET Core 2.0 application, I want to throw a `400 Bad Request` when there is a syntax problem in the input (eg malformed json) and a `422 Unprocessable Entity` for the other errors (eg Required, StringLength etc).

Is there a way to know (maybe looking into `ModelState`) if it a syntax (`400`) problem or a validation one (`422`)?

This is the controller action I am using...

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateArticle([FromBody] CreateArticleInput input)
    {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Return 400 or 422
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there is a syntax error/malformed payload the model binder won't populate the `input` parameter. Given this, you can check for `input == null`. When the requirements of the object are not met, `ModelState.IsValid` will return `false` and you can return a HTTP 422 accordingly.

Some example code:

```
public class MyObj
{
    [Required]
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}


[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]MyObj obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return UnprocessableEntity(ModelState);
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

When posting an invalid/malformed payload, `obj` will be `null` and a bad request (HTTP 400) will be returned. When the payload is correct JSON but the `Foo` property is `null`, `ModelState.IsValid` will return `false` which results in an HTTP 422 result with the validation binding errors. When all is well it will return a 200.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are asking, sounds like the `CreateArticleInput` may be some sort of JSON input - but would have thought writing your own custom model binder would be the way to go. 
Then if the 'raw' input does not map correctly to your `CreateArticleInput` you can deal with it in whichever way you want.
and possibly return the following from your modelbinder.

```
bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
return Task.CompletedTask;
```

and then

in the controller, if the `CreateArticleInput input` is null then return a 400 there..

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are doing with it, you can get it from the HttpContext

`return StatusCode(HttpContext.Response.StatusCode);`

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to mix-n-match return codes on a model binder level. Even 3rd party solutions, like FluentValidation, only allows you a single return pattern for a failed result.

As people suggested, add an additional syntax/semantic check on a controller level, and leave the input validation as is - much cleaner.